# Firestore: create subcollection from iOS SDK

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to create a subcollection within a document by using iOS SDK? I can't find any appropriate method on [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference) and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) doesn't provide any guides.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule, you don't explicitly "create" collections. Instead, you create documents and, if you've specified them as belonging to a collection that does not yet exist, then that collection will be created along the way.

So if you have a `/users/jane` document and want to add a `history` subcollection, you basically do this by creating the first document you want to appear in that subcollection -- i.e. something like:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users/jane/history").addDocument(historyData)
```

I believe this would work, too:

```
Firestore.firestore().document("users/jane/history/20171105")setData(historyData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [collection()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#/c:objc(cs)DocumentReference(im)collectionWithPath:) method on [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference) to reach into any subcollections on that document.  From the API docs:

> A DocumentReference can also be used to create a CollectionReference to a subcollection.

Read more about subcollections [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections).